# Threadsafe static initialization of ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I am trying to create a threadsafe singleton class based on Initialization-on-demand holder idiom . Here is my code

```
public class Check{ 
        private Check(){  }
        private static class Provider {
            static final ExecutorService INSTANCE = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, "read this val from file", 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue());
        }
        public static ExecutorService getInstance() {
            return Provider.INSTANCE;
        }
    }
```

My expectation is to initialize ExecutorService in threadsafe manner and only one instance should be there (static). Is it good or do i need to change something here ..

Comment: This question is not really about ExecutorService but singletons. Look at
[Implementing Singleton with an Enum (in Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285520/implementing-singleton-with-an-enum-in-java)

Comment: In C#, you can do this by just constructing the singleton in a `static` constructor.  Since C# doesn't tend to execute static constructors until they're needed, this provides a lazy singleton.  Dunno if Java has this property or not; does Java execute `static` constructors as soon as the program starts, or does it wait until the `static` class is used?